# SPARQL on Wikidata: Official languages of a country sorted by commonality

Tags: sorting, sparql, multilingual, wikidata, country

I am trying to get the languages spoken in a Country. The returned results should be returned in order. This order should be either the official ordering of the languages given by the country, if obtainable, or the order given by the number of people speaking the language. The ordering of the languages after the first one is not particularly important, but the first language returned must be either the main official language or, if not defined, it should be the most commonly spoken language.

Taking the example of Switzerland, the official languages order (given, likely, by the number of people speaking it) is, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_Switzerland): German, French, Italian, Romansh.

The [Wikidata page on Switzerland](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q39) shows the official languages in the following order: German, Italian, French, Romansh. This is not the order shown in Wikipedia. However, on the Wikidata pages I've looked at, the first language listed is consistently the main one (see example for [Spain](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q29)).

The following SPARQL query retrieves the official languages for Switzerland ([try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20schema%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0A%20%0ASELECT%20%2A%0A%7B%0A%20%20BIND%28wd%3AQ39%20as%20%3Fcountry%29%0A%20%20%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP37%20%3FofficialLanguages.%0A%20%20%20%20%3FofficialLanguages%20wdt%3AP424%20%3FofficialLanguagesCode.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)):

```
SELECT *
{
  BIND(wd:Q39 as ?country)
  
  OPTIONAL {
    ?country wdt:P37 ?officialLanguages.
    ?officialLanguages wdt:P424 ?officialLanguagesCode.
  }
}
```

This query returns yet another ordering of the languages, different from the Wikidata page ordering. The result is: French, German, Italian, Romansh. **The first language is not the main language anymore**, unlike what is shown in the Wikidata page.

##### First question

Why is the ordering returned by this query different than the ordering of the languages in the Wikidata page?

##### Second question

How can one get the ordered list of official languages spoken in a country?

Comment: "Why is the ordering returned by this query different than the ordering of the languages in the Wikidata page?" - your query just returns all bindings matching the query, nothing more nothing less. Until you explicitly ask for an ordering of the result. What you get without is whatever the underlying database gets from its internal datastructres and execution plans etc. Also note, an RDF dataset is a **set** of RDF triples, thus, there is no ordering at all. That is the task of people via querying the data then or even in the client code showing the result

Comment: Thanks @UninformedUser, you're right, the answer to the first question is quite obvious: it is normal DBMS behaviour.

Comment: mostly yes, but asking for clarification is nevertheless the best option, and the good thing, it will help others with the same issue or question. So I prefer people asking, in worst case it has been answered before, then a pointer to the answer can be given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the ordering returned by this query different than the  ordering of the languages in the Wikidata page?

When you ask a query, the output order is not relevant (you're getting a set of results). The only way for getting what you want is to explicit this information adding further data in the knowledge graph.

> How can one get the ordered list of official languages spoken in a country?

The only way is to manually add more information to Wikidata. For example, in [Q39#P37](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q39#P37) I've just added the property [proportion (P1107)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1107) as qualifier. Now you can submit the following query (sorting by `DESC(?proportion)`):

```sql
SELECT *
{
  BIND(wd:Q39 as ?country)
  
  OPTIONAL {
    ?country p:P37 [
      ps:P37 ?officialLanguage ;
      pq:P1107 ?proportion
    ] .
    ?officialLanguage wdt:P424 ?officialLanguageCode .
  }
}
ORDER BY ?country DESC(?proportion)
```

There are other alternatives for adding data to Wikidata. Another (I think sub-optimal) option to add ordering to the `official languages` could be to add a [series ordinal (P1545)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1545) qualifier to indicate an order of importance (1, 2, 3, etc.).

Currently, you don't see any qualifier in other items because, evidently, no one has raised the issue so far. Hence you can either [be bold](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Be_bold) and adding such qualifiers or open a new topic somewhere on Wikidata and see how consensus evolves.

Comment: Thanks for this. So, if I understand this right, you literally modified the entry for Switzerland in order to add the `proportion` (P1107) qualifier to the `official languages` (P37), which allows to get the result I want. Does this mean that the only correct approach to this problem is to use the `proportion` qualifier? From what I can see, no other country I looked at actually implements `proportion` under `official languages`. See e.g. [Mexico](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q96#P37) or [Portugal](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q45#P37).

Comment: @alelom Yes, the only way is to explicit it adding further data. There are many alternatives for doing this. Another (I think sub-optimal) option could be to use [series ordinal (P1545)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1545) for indicating just the order of importance (1, 2, 3, ecc.). You don't see any qualifier in other items because, evidently, no one has raised the issue so far. Hence you can either [be bold](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Be_bold) and adding such qualifiers or open a new topic somewhere on Wikidata and see how consensus evolves.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Could you incorporate your last comment in the answer? I think it would be needed to complete it. Then I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Thanks @logi-kal. Also worth commenting on this: I realised that most pages for countries are edit-protected, at least to users like me. How did you edit the page for Switzerland that fast?

Comment: @alelom In the [item's log](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Log&page=Q39) you can see that it has been protected against non-autoconfirmed users, adducing as reason "Sensitive, highly linked item". The requirement for the autoconfirmed flag for an user is being more than four days old and having more than 50 edits. See also https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/WD:PPP and https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/WD:Autoconfirmed (I don't add this in the answer since it is off-topic).